# Remapping Win + Left to Home fails with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Trying to simulate the function key + arrows where for instance <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> = <kbd>Home</kbd>.

I want to be able to hold shift and select text so Im using the wildcard * as well.

```
*<#Left::Home
```

This only works if shift is held down. Nothing happens if shift is up. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andreas,

When you define a **remapping** like you did, the original windows shortcut stays active (don't ask me why...). You could disable those pre-defined Windows hotkeys in the registry, but an easier way is to turn them into **hotkeys**. When using hotkeys and the send (or SendInput) command, the modifier keys are ignored (unlike in your clever remapping).
This means that you will have to "trap" every combination. Below I have shown the long (compared to your solution) version. Sorry, but as far as I know this is the only way (or you could use an * and test for the Shift/Ctrl/Alt keys with GetKeyState, but that makes it more complex).

```
#Left::Send, {Home}
+#Left::Send, +{Home}
```